# Aligning ImageSpan to the top of the TextView

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

Currently, I wish to add an image in between texts and align it to the top of the TextView.

Something like this:

[image]

The only vertical alignments I can find are baseline (which seems to put it right down the center of the text) and align bottom.

What happens if I use ALIGN_BASELINE is:

[image]

Is there a way to align it to the top instead?

My current code:

```
    txtView.setText(this.addImageAsterisk(
        "The string to have asterisk at the end*"), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

then

```
private CharSequence addImageAsterisk(String string) {
    Drawable d = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_asterisk); 

    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(string);
    spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, string.length()-1, string.length(), 0);
    return spannableString;
}
```

removing ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE sets it to align to the bottom which is also not my expected result.

--- Thank you user Lalit Poptani, I tried applying your answer----
after applying this, what happens is that the whole textview seems to have extra margin top.

before applying span:

```
This is the text*
```

after applying the SuperscriptSpanAdjuster

```
(some extra space)
This is the text*
```

My code:

```
String string = "This is the text*";
Drawable d = this.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_asterisk); 

d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()); 

ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
SuperscriptSpanAdjuster s = new SuperscriptSpanAdjuster(1.5);
final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(string);
spannableString.setSpan(s, string.length() - 1, string.length(), 0);
spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, string.length(), string.length() + 1, 0);
textView.setText(spannableString);
```

Comment: Share your code. And make clear what you really want by attaching a sample image.

Answer (score 9):

What you can do is use a custom `MetricAffectingSpan` for maintaining its ratio like,

```
public class SuperscriptSpanAdjuster extends MetricAffectingSpan {
    double ratio = 0.5;

    public SuperscriptSpanAdjuster(double ratio) {
        this.ratio = ratio;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint paint) {
        paint.baselineShift += (int) (paint.ascent() * ratio);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        paint.baselineShift += (int) (paint.ascent() * ratio);
    }
}
```

And the you can use `SpannableString` to apply asterisk to your String like,

```
SpannableString mString = new SpannableString("This is what I wanted*");
mString.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpanAdjuster(0.5), mString.length() - 1, 
                     mString.length(), SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
mTextView.append("\n");
mTextView.append(mString);
```

This is append asterisk to your text as you required. And your output will be as,

[image]

Comment: after applying this, what happens is that my text seems to have extra margin top.

Comment: you can increase or decrease the margin by chainging the constructor parameter of `SuperscriptSpanAdjuster(0.5)`

Comment: ah you are right :) but the SuperscriptSpanAdjuster  seem to work properly only for text but when I use it on the portion with ImageSpan, the ImageSpan still remains in the same position

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap your drawable in inset drawable and set inset bottom to some value like 8dp. Not the best solution, but will work.

Modify your `drawable/img_asterisk.xml` --

```
<inset
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetBottom="8dp">

    <!-- Your previous asterisk drawable, probably a 'shape' -->

</inset>
```