# How can I make a textview show like this. A big blue dot to the left of text

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to add a bullet or a blue dot to the left of text. I tried 
textview.settext("\u2022 my text") but the bullet is black color and is small size compared to the other text's size. 
Is it possible to insert a character to the left of text and I can change color/size of that character? I can also create a custom drawable which is a "oval" shape of blue color but how can I insert that to the left of "my text" so that the effect is as below.

[image]

SpannableString doesn't work as expected. This is what I've done.

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(" In the tumultuous business of cutting-in and attending.");
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unread_dot_shape);
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()); // <---- Very important otherwise your image won't appear
ImageSpan myImage = new ImageSpan(d);

builder.setSpan(myImage, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
subjView.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

The unread_dot_shape.xml looks like this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/my_color_blue" />
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp" />
    <size
        android:width="5dp"
        android:height="5dp" />
</shape>
```

The result looks like this.
[image]

I'd like the dot to be vertically aligned as per the original screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

Something like this:

```
  SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("string");
  ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.blue_dot);
  spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, 0);
  textView.setText(spannableString);
```

Comment: Spannable doesn't work as expected, or may be I'm doing it wrong. I've updated my question with some code.

Comment: Not sure from the top of my head - maybe try setting alignBottom on the ImageSpan? Or maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392218/aligning-imagespan-to-the-top-of-the-textview

Comment: A combination of spannablestring and some adjustments with alignbotton on the imagespan seems to give me good result.
thanks @vkislicins

Comment: @kdas Glad to hear that - select this as an answer then please

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to insert a character to the left of text

You did so, in your code snippet in your question.

> I can change color/size of that character?

You are welcome to wrap that character in `ForegroundColorSpan`, `RelativeSizeSpan`, etc., using a `SpannableString` instead of a regular string.

Or, use a `BulletSpan` and skip the character, though I don't think you can control the size of the bullet.

> I can also create a custom drawable which is a "oval" shape of blue color but how can I insert that to the left of "my text" so that the effect is as below.

Either use an `ImageSpan` or find a library that allows you to wrap text around an image in a `TextView` (I'm pretty sure there is one, though I'm not coming up with it on a quick search).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a Drawable inside your TextView.

Blue dot:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<solid android:color="@color/your_color" />
<size android:height="16dp" android:width="16dp"/> // Here you can set the size of the dot
```

And then, in your layout xml:

```
           <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_dot"
            android:text="Your Text"
            />
```

Comment: DrawableLeft doesn't work. In this case if my text is across two lines, the whole text is to the right of "dot" which I don't want. I want the "dot" to be like the part of text so that the text wraps around below the dot.